# getting both the preceding (initial) and the chosen value of a select element in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve both the initial and the chosen value of a select element within one event listener.

I attempted to fabricate something but it gives the second value two times. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<span class="curr__parent">
  <select class="add__currency">
    <option value="HUF" selected>HUF</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

JS:

```
 document.querySelector('.curr__parent').addEventListener("change",changeCurrenc);
    var changeCurrency = function(event){
    var firstCurr = document.querySelector(".add__currency").value;
    var secondCurr = event.target.value;

    console.log(firstCurr);
    console.log(secondCurr);
    };`
```

THanks a lot,
Szabi

Comment: The value will be updated before the handler is called. You'll have to maintain the previous state with your own code somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the initial value outside of the event handler scope because it only gets fired after the value is changed.

```js
 document.querySelector('.add__currency').addEventListener("change", function(e){
   changeCurrency(e);
 });

var firstCurr = document.querySelector(".add__currency").value;

var changeCurrency = function(event){
    console.log('firstCurr:', firstCurr);

    var secondCurr = event.target.value;
  
    console.log('secondCurr:', secondCurr);
    firstCurr  = secondCurr;
};
```

```html
<span class="curr__parent">
  <select class="add__currency">
    <option value="HUF" selected>HUF</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    
  </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Afron!